# Manually configuring coordinate reference system of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using qgis valmiera on windows 7 pro 64 bit.

How do I manually configure CRS. that is user defined coordinate system, so that i can manually enter the values of projection?

Answer (score 1):

For CRS:
If you want to use an existing one, you can click on CRS configuration, bottom right of QGIS, and choose the one you need. You can do the same by going to Settings->options-> CRS.
If you want to manually define your CRS, again go to Settings->Custom CRS